# PEGJS: How to pass a grammar

Tags: javascript, parsing, pegjs

Quoting from [PEGJS Tutorial](http://pegjs.majda.cz/documentation#grammar-syntax-and-semantics-parsing-expression-types):

> To generate a parser, call the PEG.buildParser method and 
>       pass your grammar as a parameter:

```
var parser = PEG.buildParser("start = ('a' / 'b')+");
```

My grammar is a bit more complicated:

```
start
  = additive

additive
  = left:multiplicative "+" right:additive { return left + right; }
  / multiplicative

multiplicative
  = left:primary "*" right:multiplicative { return left * right; }
  / primary

primary
  = integer
  / "(" additive:additive ")" { return additive; }

integer "integer"
  = digits:[0-9]+ { return parseInt(digits.join(""), 10); }
```

I should pass to `PEG.buildParser` the Starting Rule of my grammar, i.e. `additive`, but I can't get it right.
If I write 
`PEG.buildParser(additive)` or `PEG.buildParser(start)`, FireBug said 
`SyntaxError: Expected "=" or string but end of input found`;
if I write `PEG.buildParser(start = additive)`, I get `GrammarError: Referenced rule "additive" does not exist`;
what is the correct way to pass my grammar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complete grammar must be parsed to `buildParser` as a string, e.g.

```
PEG = require('pegjs');
var parser = PEG.buildParser(
  'start\n' +
  '  = additive\n' +
  '\n' +
  'additive\n' +
  '  = left:multiplicative "+" right:additive { return left + right; }\n' +
  '  / multiplicative\n' +
  '\n' +
  'multiplicative\n' +
  '  = left:primary "*" right:multiplicative { return left * right; }\n' +
  '  / primary\n' +
  '\n' +
  'primary\n' +
  '  = integer\n' +
  '  / "(" additive:additive ")" { return additive; }\n' +
  '\n' +
  'integer "integer"\n' +
  '  = digits:[0-9]+ { return parseInt(digits.join(""), 10); }'
);
console.log(parser.parse('(1+2)*3'));
```

Comment: Thank you Gunther.
Just one doubt: is there an easier way to pass the grammar?
Not as a string, maybe including an external file?

Comment: @elmazzun your question suggests that you are interested in the Javascript API - where you have to pass a string. Just read file contents into a variable, then pass that. Otherwise invoke pegjs from a command line.

Comment: PEG.js's own [online tool](https://pegjs.org/online) can generate js file for you.

Answer (score 1):

try this example if you want to load your grammar from a file and export the parser to a file

```
const peg = require('pegjs');
const fs = require('fs');

const grammarAsString = fs.readFileSync('./grammar.pegjs').toString();

const option = {
  output: 'source',
};

const parserSourceCode = peg.generate(grammarAsString, option);
fs.writeFileSync('./parser.js', parserSourceCode);

const parser = required('./parser.js');
const output = parser.parse("(1 + 2) * 3"); // output = 9
```

if you want your parser to be object and use it directly change output value from "source" to "parser" or don't pass it at all the default is parser.

```
const peg = require('pegjs');
const fs = require('fs');

const grammarAsString = fs.readFileSync('./grammar.pegjs').toString();

const parserObjet = peg.generate(grammarAsString);
const output = parserObject.parse("(1 + 2) * 3"); // output = 9
```